# PennDot registration suspension for not responding to their request.

Tags: car-insurance, penalty

My auto insurance policy expired and on the same day I purchased another policy via some other company. I received a letter from PA-DMV, requesting an update about new insurance policy information. But I did not respond to them and now they have sent me a letter notifying a suspension of car registration after one month. 
Now I already have updated my new insurance information on PennDOT website and I never missed a day without insurance. Will I still need to pay $500 penalty?

http://www.legis.state.pa.us/WU01/LI/LI/CT/HTM/75/00.017.086.000..HTM

Comment: Probably not, but you need to ask *them*, not here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a technicality and not personal finance.

Answer (score 3):

I update my latest insurance information online and called them. They have removed pending registration suspension. It appears they cannot suspend the registration if the insurance coverage was continuous.

sorry for posting this question here but there is no SE that deal with issues relating to DMV.

Comment: Glad you figured out your problem though and glad your DMV is reasonable.